# Defining the Adjunction Space

Tags: general-topology, definition

[image]

In the definition above $X \sqcup Y / \sim$ has equivalence classes as elements. So pick $[x] \in X \sqcup Y / \sim$, then $[x] = \{ y \in X \sqcup Y \ | \ y \sim x\}$, and $y \sim x$ if and only if $f(x) = y$.

Now my question is $x \in X \sqcup Y$, but $f$ is only even defined for $A \subseteq Y$, so how can $f(x)$ even be defined for $x \in X \sqcup Y$?

Comment: The relation $a\sim f(a)$ for $a\in A$ does not define an equivalence relation. That is why it says "the equivalence relation...generated by $a\sim f(a)$". A good first step before looking at the quotient is to understand exactly what the generated equivalence relation is.

Comment: Why do you think that $f(x)$ has to be defined for $x\in X$? The function $f$ is only defined on a **subset** of $X\sqcup Y$, namely on $A\subseteq Y$. The relation is as follows: if $x\in A$ then $x\sim'f(x)$. Define $\sim$ to be the smallest equivalence relation containing $\sim'$.

Comment: @freakish I never said $f(x)$ needed to be defined for $x \in X$, I said $f(x)$ needed to be defined for $x \in X \sqcup Y$. Also $A \subseteq Y \not\subseteq X \sqcup Y$, because $X \sqcup Y$ has elements of the form $(x, \alpha)$ for $\alpha \in \{1, 2\}$, whereas $Y$ has elements of the form $x$

Comment: @Perturbative This is just technicality that $X\sqcup Y$ is defined as pairs $(x, \alpha)$. You usually identify $X$ and $Y$ as subsets of $X\sqcup Y$ via canonical embeddings $x\mapsto (x,1)$ and $y\mapsto (y,2)$. So everyone simply says $Y\subseteq X\sqcup Y$ since it is obviously embeddable.

Comment: @freakish Maybe I'm being overly pedantic, but the thing is the technicality, is crucial to well-definedness of functions. So what you're saying is we say "$Y$", when we *really mean* $i[Y]$ where $i$ is the inclusion mapping $i : Y \to X \sqcup Y$, defined by $i(x) = (x, \alpha)$?

Comment: @Perturbative Well, the inclusion $i:Y\to X\sqcup Y$ is given by $i(x)=(x,2)$ (analogously for $X$ the index is $1$). With that when he writes $a\sim f(a)$ for $a\in Y$ (or $A\subseteq Y$, whatever) he actually means that $a=(y,2)$ for some $y\in Y$ and then $a\sim f'(a)$ where $f'(y,2)=(f(y), 1)$. In other words $(y,2)\sim (f(y), 1)$. This is how the technicality works. You can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so let me gather all the info from comments.

Lets start from the begining. If $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of sets then the disjoint union is defined as the set of pairs:

$$\bigsqcup_{i\in I} X_i:=\big\{(x,i)\ |\ x\in X_i\big\}\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i\times I$$

Now for any $j\in I$ we have the canonical embedding:

$$\phi_{j}:X_j\to\bigsqcup_{i\in I} X_i$$
$$\phi_{j}(x)=(x, j)$$

This function is injective (and "natural") so we identify $X_i$ with its image $X_i^*:=\phi_i(X_i)$. Also note that $X_i^*\cap X_j^*=\emptyset$ if $i\neq j$ and $\bigsqcup_{i\in I}X_i=\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i^*$ so it is a decomposition of the disjoint union.

With that we can define the topology on $\bigsqcup_{i\in I} X_i$ as follows: a subset $U\subseteq \bigsqcup_{i\in I} X_i$ is open if and only if $\phi_i^{-1}(U\cap X_i^*)$ is open in $X_i$ for all $i\in I$. Note that since we identify $X_i$ with $X_i^*$ then we can also identify corresponding open subsets and the definition can be simplified: $U$ is open iff $U\cap X_i$ is open in $X_i$ for all $i\in I$.

Finally if $f:X_i\to Y$ is some function then it induces $f^*:X_i^*\to Y$ given by $f^*(x, i)=f(x)$. It can be easily shown that topologies agree and $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^*$ is. So again we identify $f$ with $f^*$. The same applies if $(\cdot)^*$ is on codomain of $f$ or in both. We can substitute $X_i$ for $X_i^*$ (and vice versa) however we want.

---

Back to the original problem. What the author actually says is if $f:A\to X$ is a (continuous) function then he defines a relation on $X\sqcup Y$ by saying

$$(a,2)\sim \big(f(a), 1\big)\mbox{ for }a\in A$$

That's the technicality hidden behind $a\sim f(a)$.

**Ex 1.** Let $Y=[0,1]$ be the unit interval, $X=\{*\}$ be one-point space and $A=\{0,1\}$. Define $f:A\to X$ by obvious $f(0)=*$ and $f(1)=*$. The resulting $X\sqcup_{f} Y$ is homeomorphic to the 1-dimension sphere $S^1$. Actually more generally if $X=\{*\}$ then $X\sqcup_{f} Y\simeq Y/A$.

**Ex 2.** Let $X=Y=[0,1]^2\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ be a 2-dimensional unit square. Let $A=[0,1]\times\{0\}\cup[0,1]\times\{1\}$ be lower and higher boundary. Define $f:A\to X$ by $f(t, 0)=(t,0)$ and $f(t, 1)=(1-t, 1)$. So $f$ is identity on the bottom and a "twist" on the top. The corresponding quotient space $X\sqcup_{f} Y$ is the Möbius strip.

**Ex 3.** Let $X=Y=\mathbb{T}^2$ be a [two dimensional torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus). Cut "small" open disk from each $X,Y$ and define $A$ to be the boundary of the disk in $Y$. Define $f:A\to X$ to be a homeomorphism (onto image) from $A$ to the same circle (being a boundary of the disk that has been cut) in $X$. Then $X\sqcup_{f} Y$ is homeomorphic to the [genus-two surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus-two_surface). Of course I omit technical difficulties with definining everything correctly. The construction is more generally known as [the connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum). It can be shown that the connected sum doesn't depend (up to homeomorphism) on the choice of balls (as long as they are small enough, whatever that means).

Comment: I just want to thank you for taking the time to answer this in such depth, I **really** appreciate it!